# getting pixel value for image indexed by labels

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an RGB image `Img(256,256,3)` that has been segmented. The labels for this image are in an array `Lbl(256,256)` with label values ranging from `0-n` where n is the number of clusters in the image. How do I obtain the actual RGB values for pixels assigned to a specific cluster ? For example, how do I find all pixel values assigned to cluster 1 ?

I'm sure there is a very pythonic way to do this in Numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `np.where()` like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Make sample empty image
a = np.zeros((8,8),dtype=np.uint8)                                                         

# Label a couple of random pixels as "3" to find
a[2,2]=3                                                                                   
a[3,4]=3                                                                                   

# Find them
my3s = np.where(a==3)                                                                             
Out[13]: (array([2, 3]), array([2, 4]))
```